# What is a good SOAP client library for python on App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, soap

I have read that SUDS doesn't work on App Engine.
http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-suds-list/2010-03/msg00004.html

Can anyone confirm or refute this?  Can you suggest an alternative for calling SOAP services from App Engine's python runtime?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. From what I can tell, ZSI doesn't work either - at least, according to this post here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/3429ba1f952ac717?tvc=2&q=zsi

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [ElementSoap](http://effbot.org/downloads/#elementsoap)? It seems like a good option.

Comment: I have looked at it.  It's better than nothing, but it still requires a fair bit of manual work to create method wrappers for every call.  I might fall back on it in a pinch.

Anyone know of other, possibly easier options?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-python-lib/
This is a soap library from Google.  I have not had time to test it,

Comment: Thanks, but this looks more like a Google-specific API which uses SOAPpy and/or ZSI as the underlying SOAP library.  (I might consider using one of those libraries myself, but that's probably a last resort considering how many claims I have read that they're no fun work with.)